# How toogle in a Cond with a temporary htaccess Rule include a static Rule?

Tags: .htaccess

How can i toogle in a htaccess Cond with a temporary and a static Rule? It is for a maintenance time. I have SEO URLs. All URLs (URL paths) are Rewrite to /index.php. When is a maintenance time, then i will Rewrite all IPs exclude my IP to the /maintenance.php. (not in the browser adress bar. only on serverside.)
There are many Conds and Rules previous of this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Yet is search for a commend out toogle in absence of maintenance time. My IP in this example is "123.45.67.89".

working mode:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
#RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

maintenance time:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$
RewriteRule . maintenance.php [L]
#RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Is this a solution?

Comment: How do you define or control maintenance time?

Comment: allways manually by a person, my person.

Comment: ok then you can keep this way of putting a `#` to comment it out